# How to show these two matirces are similar?

Tags: matrices

How can I show that these two block matrices are similar?
$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
AB &  0\\
B  &  0\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &  0\\
B  &  BA\\
\end{bmatrix}$ where $A,B \in C^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Are $A,B$ invertible?

Comment: I don't know. All I've been given is that $A,B \in C^{n \times n}$.

Comment: What is $C^{n\times n}$? All matrices? Only invertible matrices?

Comment: @Jeb How is that related to this...?

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$ P=\begin{bmatrix}I & -A\\
0  &  I\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

such that $P^{-1}M_2P=M_1$

---

$$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}I & A\\
0  &  I\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks!